# Is there a way of cascade updating the status of related cases?

Tags: trigger, case

If I have a parent case and 50 child cases, is there a way of updating the status of the parent case that then cascades to all child cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update child cases, grab the code from the AppExchange listing at https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016caTEAQ (Auto Close Child Cases) and massage it to your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

Would a simple formula field work in your case? Since the child cases are already related to the parent case via the parent case (lookup) field, you could create a formula field like this:

[image: Formula field screenshot]

Comment: I don't think that will change the status of the child case though, I think you are suggesting adding an additional field.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't assume the child records needed to be updated. The formula field will just give you the status of the Parent Case as viewed from the Child case. This article might help you in writing a trigger to update the child cases: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000giDKAAY